# Implementing a Google Play like navigation in android application

Tags: android, android-layout

I am currently working on redesigning the UI of my android application. Just to give users ease of use I want to implement a top navigation similar to google play. Also I am targeting android SDk v2.2 as the least sdk version with which my application works.

How I can do this?

Comment: Very broad question. First search about `Fragment`, `ViewPager`, `Support library`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should checkout [this blog](http://www.pushing-pixels.org/2011/08/11/android-tips-and-tricks-swipey-tabs.html) (from one of the Google engineer working on Google Play), there are a few other posts about the Google Play application design.

To handle android SDK going back to Froyo, you'll need to use the [support library](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html),  [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/) and the [ViewPagerIndicator](http://viewpagerindicator.com/)

Comment: here is what we developed in the end https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sandhills.lokalmotion&feature=nav_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDMsImNvbS5zYW5kaGlsbHMubG9rYWxtb3Rpb24iXQ..

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you are looking for [Sherlock ActionBar](http://actionbarsherlock.com/).
And here is the sample demo in Google Play you could try it out [Sherlock ActionBar Sample Demo](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.actionbarsherlock.sample.demos&hl=en)

This library works since Android 1.6.